# why doesn't the comand print"\033[A " move the cursor up 1 line in python 2.7.4?

Tags: python

MY program does what it's supposed to do but it's a little messy.It generates a new line for every input.The average amount of inputs will be around 1200. So I have this incredibly long scrolling input. It would look much better to have all the input on the same line. The actual code is this:

```
# new.py

import colorama
from colorama import init
init ()
import sys
final_line =[]
line_out=[]
lot_number=[]
number_drawn=[]
def load():    
    line_out=[]
    first=input("enter first lot #: ")
    last=input("enter last lot#: ")
    for lot_number in range(first,last):
        line_out.append(lot_number)
        for count in range(1,6):
            print(str(lot_number))," ",
            sys.stdout.write((str(count)))
            number_drawn=input("?: " )
            print "\033[A                   \033[A"   # I got this from someone posting 
            if count!=1:                              #a similar problem 
                while number_drawn <= line_out[count-1] or number_drawn>80:

                    print "error"
                    number_drawn=input("?: ")
            line_out.append(number_drawn)                              
        final_line.append(line_out)
        line_out=[]
load()

print(" "*8),
for n in range(1,41):
    print n,  

for a in final_line:    
    print"\n",
    print a[0],(" ")*5,
    if a[1]==1:        
        sys.stdout.write (str(a[1]))
    elif a[1]<10:
        sys.stdout.write(" "*(a[1]*2-2))
        sys.stdout.write(str(a[1]))
    else:
        if a[1]<41:
            d=(a[1]-10)                   
            sys.stdout.write(" "*(a[1]*2-2+d))
            sys.stdout.write( str(a[1]))    
    for b in range(2,6):                  

        if a[b]<10:                    
            m=(a[b]-a[b-1])*2 -1
            sys.stdout.write(" "*m)
            sys.stdout.write(str(a[b]))

        elif a[b] >9 and a[b-1]<10: 
            d=(10-a[b-1])*2-1 
            m=(a[b]-10)*3+d
            sys.stdout.write(" "*m)
            sys.stdout.write(str(a[b]))
        else:
            if a[b]<41:
                m= (a[b]-a[b-1])*3-2
                sys.stdout.write(" "*m)
                sys.stdout.write(str(a[b]))


def exp2():               
    print"\n"
    for x in range(1,4):            
        print " "*8,"x"*119
    print " "*8,    
    for n in range(41,81):
        print n,

    for k in final_line:
        print "\n",
        print k[0],(" ")*5,
        counter=1
        for q in range(1,6):            
            if k[q]==41:
                sys.stdout.write(str(k[q]))
                counter=2
            if k[q]>41 and counter==1:
                m=(k[q]-40)
                sys.stdout.write(" "*((k[q]-40)*3 -3))
                sys.stdout.write(str(k[q]))
                counter=2
            elif k[q]>41:    
                p=(k[q]- k[q-1])*3-2
                sys.stdout.write(" "*p)
                sys.stdout.write (str(k[q]))
exp2()
```

The output is this:

```
enter first lot #: 1
enter last lot#: 4
1  1 ?: 1
[A                   [A
1  2 ?:                                      # I terminated the program myself
```

I've experimented with all kinds of variations(discovered "\b" causes python to print a blank line followed by a newline). And thanks to the people who showed me sys.stdout,write()
vs. print. This program wouldn't work without it

Comment: It all depends on your OS and how it handles output. Windows for instance won't respond to escape codes.

Comment: How are you running it? What shell? Try the simplest example, this works fine for me in python2. `print "\n out1 \033[A out2 \033[B out3"`

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 so I'm guessing I have a GNOME terminal. Tried this on Win8 but can't get Colorama to install. A recurring theme with Win8

Comment: kalhartt I'm using python 2.7.4 and I tried what you suggested but still get the text minus the escape code

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't really about python but how the shell would interpret the [control characters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes).

You'd observe similar behavior (as observed in your python code) if you tried any of the following commands in the shell (assuming that you're on a *nix platform):

```
echo -e "\033[A foobar \033[A"
```

or

```
echo $'\x1b\x5b\x41 foobar \x1b\x5b\x41'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with your python code. Different terminals has different capabilities. A terminal's termcap lists all the escape sequences that it supports.

ANSI terminals should support the escape sequence '\033[A'. GNOME's terminal and xterm will support it as well.

Comment: infocmp gave a list of commands but I can't make any sense out of them . They look like this blink=\E[5m. One code = some ANSI looking code.I don't know what either side means.Using "locate terminfo" got what looks like a directory with things like /lib/terminfo/a/ansi and /etc/terminfo/README but I'm denied access. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 so I think I have a GNOME terminal but not sure. Don't know where to go with this